# PostgreSQL and Python - Improve UPDATE performance

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sql-update

I need to update a table containing 8+ million entries, but the following statement

```
UPDATE mytable SET field_3 = 'TEST' WHERE id IN (12, 13, 14, ...., N)
```

is taking a long time (about 180.000 IDs to be updated ---> 2 hours and it is still ongoing).

Here the table structure (from \d output):

```
 id              | bigint                      | 
 field_1         | bigint                      | 
 field_2         | bigint                      | 
 field_3         | character varying(100)      | 
 ...
 field_N         |                             |
```

I have no indexes or constraints.

Any idea to improve the query performance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long for a comment.

Updating a row takes time, because of locking, logging, and other work that needs to be done.  Updating a lot of rows can take a lot of time.

That said, 2 hours for 180,000 rows seems like a long time -- that is fewer than 25 updates per second.  Such slowness might indicate resource contention, locking, or a plethora of triggers and indexes that need to be updated.

Often, it is more efficient to simply recreate the table:

```
create table temp_mytable as
    select . . .,
           (case when id in () then 'TEST' else field_3 end) as field_3, . . . 
    from mytable ;

truncate table mytable;

insert into mytable
    select * from temp_mytable;
```

Comment: I've just tried your solution but the first step (CREATE TABLE) after 1 hour is not finished yet... I think it is quite slow as the update statement...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that IN-lists do not implement a hashing method so it iterates over the 180,000 values of the inlist for every one of the 8 million rows.  Obviously this is slow.

You can rewrite it as a join to a VALUES list, this will probably choose a hashing method:

```
UPDATE my_table SET field_3 = 'TEST' from (values
(1177703),
(6803277),
(6573983),
(7018535),
-- 17,994 more 
(5883920),
(4581415)) foo(id) where foo.id=my_table.id
```

In my hands, this take 5 seconds to update 18,000 out of 8 million rows.

Comment: What is foo in your example? Please, can you explain better your approach?

Comment: "foo" is an alias for the virtual table created by the values list, and "id" is an alias for the single column within that virtual table.  Without aliases, they would be anonymous and so couldn't be referenced in the rest of the query, or have unhelpful defaults assigned.  This is just the composition of two features, Values lists (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-values.html) and `UPDATE...FROM` (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html)

Comment: Similar to creating an explicit temp table and populating it with id's manually, then doing the same update join. I wonder if there is any performance difference.